# How to insert $scope.table = [] into MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

on my project(deckbuilder) im pushing cards into table called $scope.decks and everything works fine but I would like to insert the deck into database. Is there any simple way to make it happen?

It looks like that (its just my practicing file):

```
        $scope.deckCount = 0;
        $scope.deck= [];

        $scope.saveDeck= function()
        {
            var newDeck= [];
            if($scope.deckCount === 5)
            {
                newDeck.push({"talia": $scope.deck});
                console.log(newDeck)
            }
            else
            {
                alert("There is no 5 cards in deck");
            }           
        };

        $scope.showDeck= function()
        {   

            document.getElementById("saved deck").innerHTML = "Twoja talia: "+ $scope.deck;
        };
```

[Picture from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOuvt.png)

Wybrane karty = Choosen cards

Comment: Can you provide an MVCE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/))? Without that, it's hard to know what `$scope.deck` or `$scope.table` contains. Do you have any PHP code which attempts saving something to a mysql table?

Comment: $scope.deck on the beginning is empty and after click im adding cards to variable called newDeck which contains array of choosen cards (u can see that on the picture which I uploaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an Angular/PHP/MySQL tutorial which contains everything you need:

[Simple task manager application using AngularJS PHP MySQL](http://angularcode.com/simple-task-manager-application-using-angularjs-php-mysql/)

You'll obviously need to adapt their examples to your code.

> ```
> $scope.addTask = function (task) {
>     $http.post("ajax/addTask.php?task="+task).success(function(data){
>         getTask();
>         $scope.taskInput = "";
>     });
> };
> ```

> ```
> <?php 
> require_once '../includes/db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
> if(isset($_GET['task'])){
>     $task = $_GET['task'];
>     $status = "0";
>     $created = time();
>
>     $query="INSERT INTO tasks(task,status,created_at)  VALUES ('$task', '$status', '$created')";
>     $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
>
>     $result = $mysqli->affected_rows;
>
>     echo $json_response = json_encode($result);
> }
> ?>
> ```

> ```
> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS angularcode_task;
> USE angularcode_task;
>
> -- Table structure for table `tasks`
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
>   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `task` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>   `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
>
> -- Insert some data for table `tasks`
> INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `task`, `status`, `created_at`) VALUES
> (1, 'My first task', 0, 1390815970),
> (2, 'Perform unit testing', 2, 1390815993),
> (3, 'Find bugs', 2, 1390817659),
> (4, 'Test in small devices', 2, 1390818389);
> ```

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try to learn sth from this tutorial. Hopefully it will help me solve the problem,